# Is it possible to review the same answer twice?

Tags: support, reviews

Earlier today I reviewed an [answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/94032/30492) which was flagged for its content and length. 
Now I reviewed again the very same answer.

How can this be possible?

Comment: When you click on your [Review History](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/history) and click on your vote to that question from before: how many people voted "Looks Okay" and how many voted "Recommend Deletion"? Maybe people decided that it's okay, because it could be seen as a way to narrate the answer the OP is searching, but later someone else flagged the question again after the initial review was over.

Comment: Or did you maybe review it in the First Post queue and the low-quality queue? Did you have all the options available? For example if you recommended deletion and then recommended deletion in the second review did it say something like "you already chose this action"?

Comment: @Secespitus, after my first review I count 4 delete/recommend deletion and 2 looks OK, then it comes my second review.

Comment: Interesting. Can you link to that review? I don't know whether I can access it but I would love to see how this looks like.

Comment: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/history

Comment: That's the history link, but it only shows my personal history. Can you click on the link where you said "Recommend Deletion" or "Looks Okay" and copy-paste where you land then? The one where you should see the votes from different people in the upper part of the site.

Comment: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/39585 but in my history I can see also other's votes.

Comment: Yeah, that's a [privilege](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) you get at 10k rep. I can only see my own reviews. But if someone links a specific review, like you did, I can see them. For example I can see 2 Recommend Deletion and 2 Deletion Votes on the review you linked. Does that post show up in your review history a second time?

Comment: Yes, I reviewed it the first time 7 hours ago. What you see there is my second review.

Comment: Could you link to the other one, too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66651/discussion-between-l-dutch-and-secespitus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [post](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/94032/28) (10k link) first went through the [First Posts queue](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/39569) and then, after flags, went through the [Low Quality queue](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/39585) from which it was deleted.

These review queues serve different purposes, and going through one of them doesn't bar a post from the others.  A post could even appear in all three of First Posts, Late Answers, and Low Quality, though any individual reviewer won't see it in both of First Posts and Late Answers.  I'm pretty sure a post can't go through the Low Quality queue more than once, but it's possible to see a post in that queue and one of the others.

Comment: First Posts and Late Answers however are related. When reviewing a post in one of them it will be removed from the other one. I can't find any related MSE post, but I am sure to have seen this behaviour on multiple occasions when looking at the review tasks available, handling one of the queues and seeing no other reviewers, but the other queue tasks gone. Just like doing something on a First Post outside of the queue removes it from the review tasks available.

Comment: @Secespitus hmm, interesting.  I thought I'd seen posts go to both, though maybe any individual reviewer only gets it in one of those two queues?

Comment: Yes, the post itself is placed in both queues if it fits the criteria. If it is *the* first post it goes to the First Post queue and if one of the first post**s** of a user is to an older question it goes to the Late Answer queue. It's quite possible to satisfy both criteria. Everybody would see a "1" in both queues in that case, assuming nothing else is happening in these queues at that moment. But once a reviewer handles the question in any way (outside of the queues or in any one of them) it disappears for him. Just like Voting to Close removes a question from your Close Votes queue.

Comment: @Secespitus In SuperUser, I can say that it's not true, or at least because how I handle the review. I usually open tabs on available queues. If I flag a post in Late Answer, and the post pop in First Answer, I usually refresh and click on I'm Done button (so it's not immediately removed from the other queue). If it's useful, this usually happen on 1 Late Answer and 1 First Post. I don't know if the post will disappear from the queue if it's not opened in other tab before.

Comment: @Vylix I never open different tabs for the queues