# Could the mods check this out - did I just cast two consecutive close votes on the same question?

Tags: support, bug, vote-to-close

[This question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/201001/which-my-hero-academia-volume-should-i-start-if-i-want-to-read-season-2), turned up in my feed, I imediatley commented and voted to close as NAW.

A couple of minutes later it turned-up in the close-question review queue. I again voted to close. Both times it (the system-interface) appeared to accept my close votes.

Is  there a record in the system of both my votes, if not, which (if not both) was not recorded.

If the interface appears to show that a vote has been registered, but it is not recorded, then this seems to need to be taken further, to meta.se as a bug perhaps.

Can anyone with the requisite privileges offer me any insight? Perhaps a system-record which can be used to further the inquiry if it seems appropriate.

Comment: does this help? https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5439/30492

Comment: Thanks, but not as such, no, I'll se what I can see from the history, but two close votes were apparently accepted by the system from this end, can I  tell which was recorded I wonder? Except it tells me that Mods may not know more than I do, and I need an employee to look. @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica

Comment: I'm doing some poking around in the question timeline and the review queue history - a first glance shows only one instance of a close vote from you, but I can do more digging.

Comment: Thanks @HDE226868 . it's clear one vote was recorded, is it possible to determine which one?

Comment: @ARogueAnt. It appears to be from the (low-quality post) queue - the timestamp of the queue completion is identical to the timestamp of the close vote. There's a bit of weird nuance I have to dig into to fully understand, though. (I don't think it's a bug, just an unusual process.)

Comment: Is there any chance you can provide this in  an answer with maybe a screenshot for use of presenting on main meta. Sure, my Wi-Fi's been erratic, but if the system appears to accept my close-votes but nothing is registered in the relevant database, then there's something at odds to the system's clarity of functioning within the system, I'm not enough of a programmer to tell where it might be. @HDE226868

Comment: @ARogueAnt. I believe that SE monitors bug reports on child metas, so they'll see this anyway - and since it's not really an issue that's been encountered elsewhere, it might be worth keeping it here for now. I gotta deal with something else, but I'll get back to you with details in a bit.

Comment: Ta muchly. R/L calls, I understand. @HDE226868

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a little bit of digging, and while I don't have an answer for what happened, I can confirm that the system only recorded one close vote from you, at 00:07:56 UTC on 4/18/21. This has the same timestamp as [the review you performed in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/77952)$^{\dagger}$, meaning that your close vote from the queue was successful. Therefore, when you tried to vote to close the question earlier from the question page, it seems like something didn't go through. Is it possible that you clicked "cancel" rather than "close question" after choosing the close reason? The buttons are right next to each other, and I've definitely done that before.

At any rate, there were no effects on the post itself, which was obviously quickly closed in due course. I guess we can consider this case still open, if you'll pardon the pun.

---

$^{\dagger}$As a side note for other folks with mod privileges: The moderator timeline shows the queue task marked as "invalidated", but that label refers to the post's status in the queue, not your vote. The question was closed before other folks could review it, so the post was automatically removed from the queue at closure; [therefore, for bookkeeping purposes, the review task is marked as "invalidated" in the history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/294717/274942). The same label is applied to the uncompleted review in the First Posts queue, which nobody got to before the question was closed. This confused me for about five minutes before I found documentation on it (see that Meta SE post).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I\ll watch out for the "cancel" and "close" trip-hazard. Even if it happened as I stated, it may not be a major issue, just a quibble about the interface design's function which may not affect many users - now I think about it.